# ember.js binding propagation order

Tags: ember.js

I know that Ember.js defers binding changes. I'm wondering if Ember.js maintains any order when it notifies bindings of changes?

here's a very contrived example:

```
{{#if App.backVisible}}
    <img {{bindAttr src=App.selectedPerson.avatar}} />
{{else}}
    name: {{App.selectedPerson.fullName}}
{{/if}}
```

then some place else I do:

```
App.set("selectedPerson", someOtherPerson)
App.set("backVisible", true)
```

Is there any guarantee that the src binding will be filled in before the backVisible property changes?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any guarantee that the src binding will be filled in before
>   the backVisible property changes?

I dont really understand why you would care about ***src*** being set before Ember sets the ***backVisible*** property. From your contrived example, the two properties seem functionally very independent.

However, if you still want to force ***src*** binding to be filled in the view, you can always force a render. In Ember, rendering is deferred through the run loop. the You can make the runloop execute immediately by calling ***Ember.run.end()***

For more info on run loop, try this link: http://blog.sproutcore.com/the-run-loop-part-1/

The blog post is from the Sproutcore days but core concept is still the same in Emberjs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you seek is **yes** (since first it updates all Ember objects, and later the UI).

However, I believe your app will stil work fine without this guarantee, i.e., since you use Ember's binding, even though App.backVisible will be updated first, and by that I even mean the generated UI (img-tag), the img-tag is still fine even with its src attribute set to "" (there is no "NPE", even if you bind it a.b.c.d and b is null).
A few millisecs later, Ember will update the src attribute to contain the updated value, and the image will be loaded and shown.
I think this is one of Ember's strong sides: state is in one place, and everything is reflected by it. Everything still works if bindings leads to no where temporarily (though usually this won't happen).